# Altium: Exported schematic page size cuts off part of schematic

Tags: altium, schematic

When I export the schematic, both through Smart PDF Wizard and through the output job files, the schematics are cut off in the bottom and right side. This hasn't happened before but I just got a new computer so I'm thinking it might be something I'm missing.
What might be wrong?

Comment: What page size do you have configured for each of: the schematic itself, the "output", and the "output container"? https://imgur.com/a/Iqofcpl

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Attie's suggestion worked. Thank you for your help!